# PHP framework for manage personal webpage for every member

Tags: php, frameworks

My institution wants that **every member** of the centre must have their **personal webpage**. They also wants that individual mast have able to build/modify their personal page as they want.

Now, how I have seen the application is -

- Members can create their own theme based personal profile.

  They can have multiple interlinked pages with navigation.

  They can upload pictures, videos inside pages.

  They can publish, suspend any page.

Is there any php based framework; which can handle the above requirements.

Thanks,
Sagar S. De

Comment: Basically any CMS (content management system) can do the job... e.g. Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla and many others... Your question is too general to recommend the best for your use.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CMS(Content Management System) rather than a framework. Take a look at [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) and [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Any CMS should satisfy it... but all will require some customisation to do exactly what you want...

A good CodeIgniter-based CMS is http://www.getfuelcms.com/ which is easy to customise.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Joomla as it provides a lot of flexibility. Look into creating your own custom extensions and components.